AWS S3 Put Object gets back java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid SSL master secret
This is the error I'm showing on my logs when my Java code tries to programmatically do a put to a S3 bucket.
Here's the Path:
My Server -> AWS CloudFront -> AWS S3
This error is on and off. That's the CloudFront to S3 Connection? Heres' the java code that I have on my server that is getting back the error message from AWS:
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(IMAGES_S3_BUCKET_NAME, filename, resizedImageFile).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

My server, I get this back from either S3 or CloudFront:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2024-04-27 01:55:03.037 ERROR 1138 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/imageUpload] due to exception [Invalid SSL master secret]

java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid SSL master secret
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.verifyMasterSecret(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:134) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.6.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]

When I check IAM, my Access Key is active.
Cloudfront sometimes directs the call to the right location. Other times it doesn't, and gives back the above error message.
What do I need to change in order for the java put command to go through 100% of the time?

Need sample code without secret to understand this issue

Please add the relevant code the your question (in a text block).

Did you find solution? I have the same issue when i tried to read an objects on aws s3 via spark (spark.read.csv('s3a://path_to_file'). Before that, everything worked fine and my colleague had the same error. It seems like some changes have been made on the aws side.

Yea, my website use to work before too. Now it doesn't. No clue why AWS is breaking. Sorry.

I was able to solve a problem by switching to JAVA 8 version. EXPORT JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
